# Objective C: Label Text (subclass of UIControl) not displayed in UITableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uicontrol

I am trying to display a `UILabel` text (subclass of `UIControl`) in a cell of a `tableview` controller.

My code as follows:

In `UIControl` label .h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIControlLabel : UIControl
{
    UILabel *userNameLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *userNameLabel;

@end
```

In `UIControl.m` file

```
#import "UIControlLabel.h"

@implementation UIControlLabel

@synthesize userNameLabel;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{

    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        NSLog(@"in init with frame method");
        self.userNameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];        


        [self addSubview: userNameLabel];

    }
    return self;
}


@end
```

In tableviewcontroller .m file

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"PlaceholderCell";

    int row = [indexPath row];

    Answer *thisAnswer = [self.array objectAtIndex:row];

    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier] autorelease];   

        UIControlLabel *control = [[UIControlLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 10,100, 10)];
        control.userNameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:13.0];
        control.tag = 2;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:control];

    }

    UIControlLabel *thisControl = (UIControlLabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2];
    thisControl.userNameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",thisAnswer.userName];

return cell;
}
```

My issue is that the cell is not showing the label i set above. Is there something I am missing out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you're not setting a frame for your UILabel within your class.

Either call `sizeToFit` on UILabel, set the frame to match the whole size of your cell, use `autosizeMask` or implement `-layoutSubviews` in your UIControlLabel (then you might need to call `[cell setNeedsLayout]`.